# Правильное оформление запроса MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

Правильно ли такое оформление запроса? Выводит пустую таблицу при добавлении: HAVING datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
Или подскажите как отобрать данные за последний час?

```
sql = """
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, time), '%d.%m.%Y%h:%i:%s') AS datetime,
    last,
    vol,
    oper
    FROM all_trades
    HAVING datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
"""
```

Пример данных до запроса:

```
             date      time    last  vol  oper
0      14.10.2019  10:48:03  132330    1     S
1      14.10.2019  10:00:00  132840   24     B
2      14.10.2019  10:48:03  132330    1     B
3      14.10.2019  10:00:00  132840    1     S
4      14.10.2019  10:00:00  132830    1     S
```

Пример данных после запроса:

```
                 datetime    last  vol  oper
0     2019-10-14 10:48:03  132330    1     S
1     2019-10-14 10:00:00  132840   24     B
2     2019-10-14 10:48:03  132330    1     B
3     2019-10-14 10:00:00  132840    1     S
4     2019-10-14 10:00:00  132830    1     S
```

DDL таблицы:

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date  | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time  | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last  | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vol   | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| oper  | varchar(7) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Полное оформление запроса:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='******', db='quotes')

sql = """
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, time), '%d.%m.%Y%h:%i:%s') AS datetime,
    last,
    vol,
    oper
    FROM all_trades
    HAVING datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
"""

df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, connection)
connection.close()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99880/discussion-on-question-by-tortuga----mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш запрос мягко говоря "не оптимален".
Использую `having`, получается что базе данных приходится сначала преобразовать всю вашу таблицу к нужному виду, а потом уже отсекать лишние данные. Если таблица будет более менее большая, то ваш запрос начнет дико тормозить.
Для оптимизации вашего запроса, для начала предлагаю отсечь всё по дате добавив:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') = date
```

Это уже сильно снизит количество обрабатываемых данных.

А чтобы сделать отсчеку по времени, можно использовать сравнение строк:

```
and DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s') < time
```

Только надо следить, чтобы данные в сравнении точно совпадали по формату.

Единственно, что в этом случае не будет работать переход на новую дату. Но и тут можно что-нибудь придумать не используя `having`.

Comment: *Для оптимизации вашего запроса, для начала предлагаю отсечь всё по дате добавив* На "переходе" даты даст ошибочный результат.

Comment: Да. Я об этом написал в последнем абзаце.

Comment: Дата всегда будет настоящий день. По этому не страшно с переходом. А вот данных около 200 000 строк за весь день

Comment: В таком случае, мой пример должен сработать хорошо. Но в целом соглашусь с @Akina, лучше пересмотреть структуру хранения и использовать `datetime`.

Comment: Каким образом добавить следующий запрос если ваш запрос будет первым на отсечение лишнего, а далее на преобразование данных?

Comment: А почему именно "следующий"? Преобразование данных можно добавлять прям в этом запросе. На крайний случай можно обернуть этот запрос в подзапрос, но я сейчас даже не придумаю в каких случаях это может понадобиться.